# How to catch refresh (F5) and load the action where we are with struts2

Tags: javascript, struts2

Pressing the refresh browser I want it to be loaded the action in which they are. I use to load pages jsp struts2 through tiles.

this in struts.xml

```
<result-types>
    <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
</result-types>

<action name="StrutsAction" class="com.action.StrutsAction" method="methodNamne">
    <result name="success" type="tiles">tilesPage</result>
</action>
```

this in tile.xml

```
<definition name="tilesPage" extends="baseLayout">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="....." />
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/pages/page.jsp" />
</definition>
```

Comment: Which browser are you using? Try `Ctrl` + `F5` or `Shift` + `F5`.

Comment: My question is not very clear. If I press F5, the application should always be in the home. I want him to stay on the page where I was. From any browser. I wanted to know if there's a way to do it in strust2 without intercept the refresh button in javascript.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get